# firebase cloud storage restrict read of access token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have an app that allows the user to upload images to **Firebase Cloud Storage**, stores the downloadUrl in Firestore DB, and read it (show it on the app) later on, using the **downloadUrl**, which includes the **Access Token**.

My cloud storage security rules restricts read / write to authenticated users only (as the sample [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security)) **but** seems like anyone can access those images, outside of the app, by **using the Access Token** (via web browser for example).

So if someone gets the downloadUrl (stored in Firestore DB) he can access the images....
Am I missing something here?
How can I restrict access to those images from outside the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download URL contains a download token which acts as a security measure to restrict access only to those who **possess** the token. The download token is created **automatically** whenever a file is uploaded to Cloud Storage for Firebase. It's a random UUIDv4, which makes the URL hard to guess.

There's no way that you can restrict that URL (not even through Firebase Storage Security Rules). **It is always public**. This is commonly known as a "*public, unguessable URL*". There is also a revoke option through the Firebase Console just in case the URL leaks.

The Security Rules will only apply to those URL that doesn't have the Access Token included e.g.: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<bucket>/o/<file>?alt=media`.
If this URL will be accessed unauthenticated with these sample Security Rule applied:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

You will be given an error like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied."
  }
}
```

However, As I pointed out, you don't need to be concerned about this URL (with access token) as in practice it is very hard to guess but if you don't want to store a shareable public URL (which is with the Access Token) then I would suggest using the [Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) provided by Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.
So would it be a good practice to store the downloadUrl in the DB (Firestore), or should I generate a downloadUrl each time I want to retrieve / show the image from the storage?

Comment: If the object is supposed to be viewed by the public then I see no reason why not to store the `downloadURL` into the Firestore db. That should depend on your use-case, if the object is not supposed to be public then its best not to store it in your db but as I said on my answer, you can revoke the access token anytime if you want and it will generate a new access token and the URL stored on your db is now useless because the access token stored is now revoked.

Comment: Just a tip, you can customize the access token by setting a custom metadata to an object. For example object A should be accessed by token A but not token B. You may check this [guide](https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens) for more examples.